Is there a function in Excel that returns if a value is unique within a column?
I am creating a metadata excel for a database of raw data files, I have entries like this:



station
variable
year_from
year_to
ID




Berlin
T
1998
2001
T_berlin_1998


Berlin
T
2002
2023
T_berlin_2002 !!


Berlin
Q
2002
2023
Q_berlin_2002


Berlin-Pankow
T
2002
2015
T_berlin_2002 !!


Berlin-Pankow
Q
2001
2015
Q_berlin_2001



I thought I create a short ID like variable_first-six-letters-of-stationname_year (e.g. T_berlin_1998), which is easy to find for both computers and also human-readable (and not just a super long number). However, the ID has to be unique, so I would like to be able to check for that, because it could be that I get two ID's that are the same by the way I though of so far (e.g. T_berlin_2002.
Is there a function in Excel that returns if a value is unique within a column?
I found UNIQUE(), but that function returns the unique values from an array, which is not what I need, and I cannot currently think of a way to use it to get to the result I want. Ideally, I would get a warning (e.g. colour the cell red, output of a text) when the ID-formula (ID = variable&station&yearfrom) produces a value that already occurs in said column.

COUNTIF might be what you need. e.g, if your data is in range A1:E6, then in column F, you can use =COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)>1, and then fill down.

Conditional formatting rule to mark duplicates:
=COUNTIF(E:E,E1)>1 applied to E:E range:


If your data is in a table then you can add a new column and have this formula:
=COUNTIF([ID],[@ID])  anything that isn't 1 is duplicated.
If you data is in a range of cells then use this formula and drag down as you add more data:
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E2,E2) this will number the duplicates - so the unique first one will be 1, first duplicate will be 2 and so on.
